# Cannot find Xamarin.UI Cross-Platform Test Project in Visual Studio and create UI tests for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, testing, xamarin.forms, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to write UI tests for Xamarin Forms app (just for Android for the start). According to various tutorials I should see:

```
Add new project > Visual C# > Test > Xamarin.UI Cross-Platform Test Project
```

But I can only see these type of test projects:
[image: Test projects]

Which type should I choose for UI test or do I get Xamarin.UI Cross-Platform Test Project shown here? Maybe I need to install something?